# MS Forms Dropdown to Sharepoint List column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, dropdown, flow, microsoft-forms

I've used MS Flow to successfully connect a MS Form to a SP List and all text field data is getting transferred successfully, except for a dropdown column in the form.

On the SP list side, I have a multi-line text field, to which the MS Forms dropdown is mapped to. However, upon submission, while all other fields get population, the field for the dropdown remains empty.

What do I need to do to get the data stored properly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce this. I have a form with a drop-down, a sharepoint list with a multi-line text field, and a flow that transfers data from new form entries to the list.

Perhaps take out the field reference and add it back to the flow? Or, once the flow has run, look at the debugging info by clicking on the run history, and confirm that the values are being picked up by the form "get response details" action.

Comment: Thank you. This helped trace and fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with Muiltline text field. The fix for me was to use Flow to add it to a "Single Text Field" in the SP list.